# how to initialize an array without any error?

Tags: c++

My code is following for finding maximum in an array

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i;
    int array[i]={1,2,3,4,5}
    int temp;
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
            if(array[i]>temp)
            temp=A[i];
            }
            cout<<"the maximum number is "<<temp<<endl;
            return 0;
            }
```

but im getting error in line of initializing array why is that so? how do we initialize array?

Comment: what did you expect `int array[i]={1,2,3,4,5}` to mean? (and, you forgot a `;`)

Comment: Please read the basics from book, and read about initialization. `int i;` and then `int array[i]`. What size do you expect for the array?

Comment: `int array[i]` Either initialize `i` properly, or use a number instead!

Answer (score 2):

You can't define the size of an array with a runtime variable.

To fix this you can use `constexpr`:

```
constexpr int i = 5;
int array[i]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

or:

```
int array[]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

In the latter the size is deduced by the compiler.

---

Otherwise, if you need a runtime size, you'll have to use `std::vector` or any other "*dynamic*" container from the standard library:

```
int i = ...;
std::vector<int> array(i); // reserve `i` cells
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
int array[]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all variable i was not initialized

```
int i;
```

So it has some arbitrary value.

Secondly the size of a defined array shall be a constant exprssion. So even if i would be initialized this definition

```
int array[i]={1,2,3,4,5}
```

is also invalid. Moreover you forgot to place a semicolon after the closing brace.

Also you did not initialized variable temp

```
int temp;
```

And at last this control statement of the loop

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
```

is also incorrect because the array has only 5 elements.

And one more identifier A was not declared

```
temp=A[i];
```

The correct code could look as

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int N = 5;
    int array[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int max = array[0];

    for ( int i = 1; i < N; i++ )
    {
            if ( max < array[i] ) max = array[i];
    }

    cout << "the maximum number is " << max << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: or even `int main() { std::cout << "the maximum number is " << std::max({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) << std::endl; return 0;` in C++11 :)

Comment: @Jarod42 I think that 1) this is an assignment of using arrays 2) he knows nothing about standard algorithms yet